# Jackson deserialization when POJO does not match JSON structure

Tags: json, jersey, jackson

I have some json :

```
{
  key: "CORE-19",
  fields: { summary: "iblah" }
}
```

I want to pack it into a POJO that looks more like:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class JiraIssue
{
    private String mKey;
    private String mSummary;

    public String getKey(){ return(mKey);}
    public void setKey(String inKey){mKey = inKey;}
    public String getSummary(){return(mSummary);}
    public void setSummary(String summary){  mSummary = summary; }
}
```

So basically I don't want to create a 'Fields' object as it is a bit superfluous for my needs. However I really can't see any way in Jackson to tell it that the 'summary' property actually comes from the 'fields' property. Is this possible?

Serialization of this class is not a concern, it will only ever be used for Deserialization. I have no control over the JSON format as it is coming from an external source (and the above is just a snippet). Also I'm actually using Jackson with Jersey.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually an open [issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-781) for this kind of structural change. There is no way as of now to do that easily with annotation only without modifying your class. What you could do instead is handle the "fields" property as a "false" property, by adding the following method:

```
public void setFields(Map<String, String> fields) {
    setSummary(fields.get("summary"));
}
```

This way you "unwrap" the property yourself.

Comment: Thanks for that! Good to know it wasn't me just missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@JsonProperty("fields.summary")
private String mSummary;
```

Comment: You can't do that with Jackson.